# How to make a Publisher from array of Publishers?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

I am using Swift Combine and would like to make a `Publisher` that was created from an array of `Publisher`. It should emit an array of elements every time one of the Publishers in the array emits a new element.

In `RxSwift` would be like the following:

```swift
 let obs1 = PublishSubject<Int>()
 let obs2 = PublishSubject<Int>()
 let arrayObs = [obs1, obs2)]

 Observable.combineLatest(arrayObs)
    .subscribe(onNext: { arrayOfLatest in
        print(arrayOfLatest) //prints an array of integers
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

obs1.onNext(5) 
obs2.onNext(10) // prints [5,10]
obs1.onNext(12) // prints [12,10]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't insist too strongly on the "array" part, `combineLatest` or `zip` is correct for the Combine framework too. The difference between them is whether you want the overall value emitted each time to contain the *oldest* (`zip`) or the *newest* (`combineLatest`) contribution from each publisher.

Your example doesn't actually give enough information to tell which of those you want. To know which you want, you'd need to say what should happen when you say e.g.:

```
obs1.onNext(5) 
obs1.onNext(6) 
obs2.onNext(10)
```

Be that as it may, Combine is Swift, so it uses a *tuple,* not an array, to express the totality of values. But if, as in your example, all the publishers have the same output and failure types, then an array can easily be substituted by mapping. See [How to zip more than 4 publishers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60345806/how-to-zip-more-than-4-publishers) for an example turning `zip` into an array processor. Exactly the same technique works for `combineLatest`.

So, here's an actual working example; to make the example more general than yours, I used three publishers instead of two:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let obs1 = PassthroughSubject<Int,Never>()
    let obs2 = PassthroughSubject<Int,Never>()
    let obs3 = PassthroughSubject<Int,Never>()
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let arr = [obs1, obs2, obs3]
        let pub = arr.dropFirst().reduce(into: AnyPublisher(arr[0].map{[$0]})) {
            res, ob in
            res = res.combineLatest(ob) {
                i1, i2 -> [Int] in
                return i1 + [i2]
            }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        pub.sink { print($0) }.store(in: &storage)
        obs1.send(5)
        obs2.send(10)
        obs3.send(1) // [5, 10, 1]
        obs1.send(12) // [12, 10, 1]
        obs3.send(20) // [12, 10, 20]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy with combineLatest. The passed-down value is a tuple, not an array.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

let obs1 = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let obs2 = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

let sub = obs1.combineLatest(obs2).sink { (first, second) in
    print("\(first) \(second)")
}

obs1.send(5)
obs2.send(10) // prints 5 10
obs1.send(12) // prints 12 10
```

Since you come from RxSwift this cheat sheet might help https://github.com/CombineCommunity/rxswift-to-combine-cheatsheet

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a combineLatest() that accepts an array of publishers as required. They're limited to only combining 2-4 publishers and from an argument list that must be specified in code.

Comment: why is nothing printed when obs1.send(5) ?