# Call two Swift Combine calls where the second call depends on the result of the first call

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm new to Swift Combine, so having a small issue

Im trying to call two api calls, and merge the results as the second API call depends on the result from the first call.

Here is the code

```
return self.gameRepository.fetchGames(forUser: user.id)
            .map { games -> AnyPublisher<[Game], ApiError> in
                let result = games.map { gameDto -> Game in
                    let location = self.venueRepository.fetch(by: gameDto.siteId)
                        .map { $0.mapToModel() }
                    let game = gameDto.mapToModel(location: location)
                    return game
                }
```

My error is on line 4 "let location" the compiler complains when I try and pass this through to 
line 5

```
game.mapToModel(location: location)
```

Cannot convert value of type 'AnyPublisher' to expected argument type Location

The fetch call signature from the repository looks like this

```
func fetch(by id: String) -> AnyPublisher<LocationDto, ApiError>
```

So it is correct, but the .map call I use on the result allows the

```
$0.mapToModel()
```

to occur, so I have locationDto object that allows me to cast to my Domain model.

Any help on how I can call these two apis together would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are probably looking for either `flatMap` or `switchToLatest`. But you might also need to use `MergeMany`.

Comment: There is a good topic that provides many approaches to solve tasks like yours [Combine framework serialize async operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743938/combine-framework-serialize-async-operations), it should be helpful. Of course I recommend my approach :^), but it does not important.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the first map operator, try to use flatMap and return from this .flatmap AnyPublisher with your model, that needs to be passed to another request. Pseudocode:

```
fetchGames -> AnyPublisher<[Game]> // First request
fetchGame(by id: String) -> AnyPublisher<LocationDto> // Second request that depends on model from first one

fetchGames.flatMap { fetchGame(by: $0.id) }
```