# Memory leak when using `Publishers.Sequence`

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a function that create collection of Publishers:

```
func publishers(from text: String) -> [AnyPublisher<SignalToken, Never>] {
     let signalTokens: [SignalToken] = translate(from: text)
     var delay: Int = 0
     let signalPublishers: [AnyPublisher<SignalToken, Never>] = signalTokens.map { token in
         let publisher = Just(token)
                           .delay(for: .milliseconds(delay), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
         delay += token.delay
         return publisher
     }
     return signalPublishers
}
```

In service class I have to method, one for `play()`:

```
func play(signal: String) {
     anyCancellable = signalTokenSubject.sink(receiveValue: { token in print(token) }

     anyCancellable2 = publishers(from: signal)
         .publisher
         .flatMap { $0 }
         .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
         .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] token in
            self?.signalTokenSubject.send(token)
         })
}
```

and one for `stop()`:

```
func stop() {
     anyCancellable?.cancel()
     anyCancellable2?.cancel()
}
```

I've had problem with memory. When collection of publishers is large and I `stop()` before whole `Publishers.Sequence` is `.finshed` memory increase and never release.

Is there a way to `completed` `Publishers.Sequence` earlier, before Combine iterate over whole collection?

Answer (score 1):

To reclaim the memory, release the pipelines:

```
func stop() {
     anyCancellable?.cancel()
     anyCancellable2?.cancel()
     anyCancellable = nil 
     anyCancellable2 = nil 
}
```

Actually you don't need the `cancel` calls, because releasing the pipelines does cancel in good order; that is the whole point of AnyCancellable. So you can just say:

```
func stop() {
     anyCancellable = nil 
     anyCancellable2 = nil 
}
```

Another thing to note is that you are running all your publishers at once. The sequence does not arrive sequentially; the *whole* sequence is dumped into the `flapMap` which starts all the publishers publishing simultaneously. Thus cancelling doesn't do you all that much good. You might want to set the `maxPublishers:` on your `flatMap` so that backpressure prevents more than some small number of publishers from arriving simultaneously (like for example one at a time).

Comment: See also the whole discussion here about serializing a sequence of publishers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743938/combine-framework-serialize-async-operations

Comment: Also, from what I remember, `Delay` publisher doesn't cancel (still sends a value after receiving cancel)

Comment: @NewDev Correct of course, good point. Once the publisher has started to publish, values may come in. But you don't have to be there to receive them. :)

Comment: But doesn't that mean that something (some closure?) is possibly self-retaining, at least until it completes, which would account for memory increase. And I think if you had `let c = pub.sink{print($0)}`, it would still print even after `c.cancel()` (I remember this being a surprise to me)