# dispatch group and Threading swift (Async Await)

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

So I was practicing threading and I have a requirement.
I want to wait for the first api call to finish then I want to execute the second one, (Just like await async) if the first one didn't finish I want to stop the code there until it finishes.

So, I wrote this. Tell me if it is correct or if there is any better way to do this

```
func myFunction() {
    var a: Int?
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
        a = 1
        print("First")
        group.leave()
    }
    group.wait()
    group.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        a = 3
        print("Second")
        group.leave()
    }
    // wait ...
    group.wait()
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print(a) // y
    }
}
```

Comment: asyncafter are just api calls, This async after is implying that this is an api call which will take this much seconds to complete the real question is how to wait for the api response before executing the next api call, That was the actual question

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5.5 and Xcode 13.0 bring async/await, so you can do something like this:

```swift
import Foundation

print("Hello, World!")

// Returns a 1 after a 3-second delay
func giveMeAOne() async -> Int {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3.0)
    return 1
}

// Returns a 5 after a 3-second delay
func giveMeAFive() async -> Int {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3.0)
    return 5
}

func myFunction() async {
    var a: Int = 0
    print(a)
    a += await giveMeAOne()
    print(a)
    a += await giveMeAFive()
    print(a)
}

async {
    await myFunction()
}

sleep(7) // added at the end so that process doesn't exit right away
```

Note that the above was built as a macOS command-line tool in Xcode, rather than with Swift Playgrounds.  As of **Xcode 13.0 beta 1**, Swift Playgrounds fail on a **lot** of async/await stuff, unfortunately.

That code above runs them sequentially, and cleans up **myFunction** quite a bit.  Note that this doesn't introduce any *concurrency*, however.  Both **giveMeAOne()** and **giveMeAFive()** are run sequentially.

If you wanted to run 4 function calls ***concurrently***, you could do something like this:

```swift
/// Returns a random integer from 1 through 10, after a 6-second delay
func randomSmallInt() async -> Int {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 6)
    return Int.random(in: 1 ... 10)
}

/// Fetches 4 random integers, summing them
func myFunction() async {
    // print timestamp
    print(Date())
    async let a = randomSmallInt()
    async let b = randomSmallInt()
    async let c = randomSmallInt()
    async let d = randomSmallInt()
    
    // This awaits for a, b, c, and d to all complete.
    // You can only await a value once.
    let numbersToAdd = await [a, b, c, d]
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbersToAdd {
        print("adding \(number)")
        sum += number
    }
    print("Sum = \(sum)")
    
    // print another timestamp, so you can see that the async let statements ran
    // concurrently, rather than sequentially
    print(Date())
}

async {
    await myFunction()
}

// make sure we have time to finish before process exits
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10)
```

When you run this, you can see from the timestamps that the total execution time only took about 6 seconds -- because all of the `async let ...` statements were executed concurrently.

This works great if you have a fixed number of things you need to call asynchronously.  But what if you wanted to make 100 asynchronous function calls, perhaps loading images or something?

You may think you could do something like this, which will work, but will run everything **synchronously** -- probably **not** what you want:

```swift
// Don't do this -- these all run sequentially
var sum = 0
for _ in 0 ..< 100 {
    async let value = randomSmallishInt()
    let number = await value
    print("Adding \(number)")
    sum += number
}
```

If you want to do an **arbitrary** or **unknown** number of asynchronous things, the best way it to use a `taskGroup`.  This code is a bit more verbose than it needs to be, in order to make things clearer.  ***Note: Xcode 13.0 beta struggles with respect to `print` statement output, missing much of it***.  Anyway, here it is:

```swift
/// Returns a random integer from 1 through 10
func randomSmallInt() async -> Int {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 6)
    return Int.random(in: 1 ... 10)
}

func myFunction_arbitrary_repetitions_asynchronously() async {
    // print timestamp
    print(Date())
    
    // This is pretty cool -- 
    // `withTaskGroup` creates a context for executing a group of async tasks
    // In this case, `Int.self` specifies that each individual task will return
    // an Int.  `[Int].self` specifies that the entire group will return an array of Ints:
    let numbers = await withTaskGroup(of: Int.self, returning: [Int].self) { group in
        // Repeat 100 times
        for _ in 0 ..< 100 {
            // Run the next thing asynchronously
            group.async {
                return await randomSmallInt()
            }
        }
        
        // Iterate through results
        var result: [Int] = []
        for await individualResult in group {
            result.append(individualResult)
        }
        return result
    }
    
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        print("Adding \(number)")
        sum += number
    }
    print("Sum = \(sum)")
    // print another timestamp, so you can see that the async let statements ran
    // concurrently, rather than sequentially
    print(Date())
}

async { await myFunction_arbitrary_repetitions_asynchronously() }
Thread.sleep(10)
```

You could shorten this up considerably:

```swift
func myFunction_arbitrary_repetitions_asynchronously_short() async {
    // print timestamp
    print(Date())
    
    // In this case, the taskGroup just returns the sum
    let sum = await withTaskGroup(of: Int.self, returning: Int.self) { group in
        // Repeat 100 times
        for _ in 0 ..< 100 {
            // Run the next thing asynchronously
            group.async {
                return await randomSmallInt()
            }
        }
        
        // Iterate through results
        var sum = 0
        for await individualResult in group {
            print("Adding \(individualResult)")
            sum += individualResult
        }
        return sum
    }

    print("Sum = \(sum)")
    // print another timestamp, so you can see that the async let statements ran
    // concurrently, rather than sequentially
    print(Date())
}
async { await myFunction_arbitrary_repetitions_asynchronously_short() }
```

Important: **Xcode 13.0 beta 1** gets ***quite*** unstable when dealing with this code.  Specifically, the debugger likes to detach when the process isn't finished yet.  For example, the output of many of the `print` statements does not appear, and using breakpoints is tough with async code.  Building a command-line tool and then running the resulting executable (found in **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug**) will at least show all the output of your print statements.

Comment: Thank for the brilliant answer, but do you know how to switch between any-different-priority tasks? Fore example, if I want to update UI after `await myFunction_arbitrary_repetitions_asynchronously_short()`, how can I do this without using DispatchQueue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't wait.

Run the second API call in the *completion handler* of the first

```
func myFunction() {
    var a = 0
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
        a = 1
        print("First")
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            a = 3
            print("Second")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(a)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup that would be a one way to do it

Comment: This works but after studying concurrency in detail i saw this takes a lot of time and delay time as well because this will never run concurrently, DispatchGroup are the best options instead of this one or one should use operation Queue

Answer (score 1):

> Just like await async

The lack of a built-in language-level `await async` mechanism is a serious issue for Swift, and will probably be remedied in a future version. In the meantime, Swift has basically *no* built-in language-level mechanism for threading; you have to deal with things manually, by talking to either Cocoa/Objective-C (Grand Central Dispatch, NSOperation) or some other framework that deals with asynchronicity (Combine).

The particular problem you've focused on is what I call *serializing asynchronicity*. There are several ways to do this.

### Grand Central Dispatch

The simple way is, as you've been told, perform the second async call at the end of the execution handler of the first async call. This is not very general for lining up numerous tasks, obviously.

You can certainly use DispatchGroup in the way you have outlined. Your statement of the pattern is almost correct. You do not need the last `wait`, and, more important, you must get onto a background queue right at the start, because using DispatchGroup on the main queue is illegal; your code, as it stands, effectively block the main queue while we wait, which is something you must not do.

### Operation Queue

You can make a serial OperationQueue and load Operation objects onto it. This is a much more general mechanism. You can make Operation objects depend upon one another. Before the arrival of the Combine framework, this was the best general solution.

### Combine Framework

If you can confine yourself to iOS 13 and later, the Combine framework is the neatest way to serialize asynchronicity in a general way. See for further discussion [Combine framework serialize async operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743938/combine-framework-serialize-async-operations).

Comment: Thanks, actually am not very well versed in combine that's why I didn't know it can be done easily with that I am looking into it